# What is the name of the += method for hash?

Tags: ruby

I want to rewrite this:

```
my_hash['a'] += 5
```

in something like this:

```
my_hash. send (:[]+=, 'a', 5)
```

but `:[]+=` isn't working.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In Ruby an associative array is called *hash*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
my_array.send(:[]=, 'a', my_array['a'] + 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's syntactic sugar for:

```
my_array['a'] = my_array['a'] + 5
```

So the method is `+` on the element (not the array), and `[]` and `[]=` on the array itself. (Or more precisely here, on the hash.)